# get file content from variable which is image

Tags: php, mysql, file-get-contents

What function should I use to get file content (jpg) from variable which comes from:

```
 $filename = 'temporary.jpg';
 $percent = 2.5;
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
 $newwidth = $width * $percent;
 $newheight = $height * $percent;
 $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
 $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);    
 imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
```

To be more specific I'm talking about $thumb variable which is image.
I want do this to unpack this data, and then send to DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image storing functions like `imagejpeg()` output the data to the browser by default. You can capture that and save it into a variable like so:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($thumb);
$thumbData = ob_get_clean();
```

Then insert that to the database as any other (binary) string.